# How do I make the column for the metric choosable via a filter in apache superset?

Tags: filter, metrics, apache-superset

I have the outputs of several different features in several different columns in the same table, like this:

[image]

I want to make a chart where I can choose what feature should be looked at. How can I do that?

I tried the normal filters in the dashboard and I tried to make a custom SQL for the metric but it didn't work out. Can somebody pleas help me?

It schould kinda work like this:
[image: Filters I need and the graph]